# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0

Tags: java, android-studio, github

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: bettervideoplayer
```

I get such an error. What could be the solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error by updating from

```
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
```